# Ruby cannot stat a file with a pound/hash character

Tags: ruby, file

Behold:

```
bear@ptah:~/Pictures/Wallpapers
$ stat /home/bear/Dropbox/.#NineFoxes.org
  File: /home/bear/Dropbox/.#NineFoxes.org -> polar@fennec.3781:1659418908
  Size: 28              Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   symbolic link
Device: 10306h/66310d   Inode: 57016400    Links: 1
Access: (0777/lrwxrwxrwx)  Uid: ( 1000/    bear)   Gid: ( 1000/    bear)
Access: 2022-09-23 12:31:49.280214712 -0700
Modify: 2022-08-07 22:25:24.000000000 -0700
Change: 2022-09-23 12:31:49.532216732 -0700
 Birth: 2022-09-23 12:31:49.280214712 -0700
bear@ptah:~/Pictures/Wallpapers
$ stat /home/bear/Dropbox/foo.log
  File: /home/bear/Dropbox/foo.log
  Size: 1471            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 10306h/66310d   Inode: 57016411    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/    bear)   Gid: ( 1000/    bear)
Access: 2022-09-23 12:31:49.280214712 -0700
Modify: 2022-09-10 23:28:04.000000000 -0700
Change: 2022-09-23 12:31:50.116221410 -0700
 Birth: 2022-09-23 12:31:49.280214712 -0700
bear@ptah:~/Pictures/Wallpapers
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> File.stat '/home/bear/Dropbox/foo.log'
=> #<File::Stat dev=0x10306, ino=57016411, mode=0100644, nlink=1, uid=1000, gid=1000, rdev=0x0, size=1471, blksize=4096, blocks=8, atime=2022-09-23 12:31:49.280214712 -0700, mtime=2022-09-10 23:28:04 -0700, ctime=2022-09-23 12:31:50.11622141 -0700>
irb(main):002:0> File.stat '/home/bear/Dropbox/.#NineFoxes.org'
Traceback (most recent call last):
        5: from /usr/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
        4: from /usr/bin/irb:23:in `load'
        3: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/irb-1.2.6/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        2: from (irb):2
        1: from (irb):2:in `stat'
Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_stat - /home/bear/Dropbox/.#NineFoxes.org)
irb(main):003:0>
```

The filename is simply correct; that is the file and Ruby fails to stat it.  Linux can, everything else can.  Ruby can stat a file without a hash in it, also.  What is needed to render this file usable to Ruby?  (No, renaming is not an option; I need to stat the file.)

Note: This is the filename that Dir.glob finds, also.  This is the filename that Ruby thinks it has.

```
irb(main):003:0> x = Dir.glob('Dropbox/*.org', File::FNM_DOTMATCH)
=> ["Dropbox/NineFoxes.org", "Dropbox/.#NineFoxes.org", "Dropbox/Elf.org", "Dropbox/Midra.org"]
irb(main):004:0> File.stat(x[0])
=> #<File::Stat dev=0x10306, ino=57016406, mode=0100744, nlink=1, uid=1000, gid=1000, rdev=0x0, size=38102, blksize=4096, blocks=80, atime=2022-09-23 12:31:49.280214712 -0700, mtime=2022-07-29 22:00:02 -0700, ctime=2022-09-23 12:31:50.11622141 -0700>
irb(main):005:0> File.stat(x[1])
Traceback (most recent call last):
        5: from /usr/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
        4: from /usr/bin/irb:23:in `load'
        3: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/irb-1.2.6/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        2: from (irb):5
        1: from (irb):5:in `stat'
Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_stat - Dropbox/.#NineFoxes.org)
irb(main):006:0> File.stat(x[2])
=> #<File::Stat dev=0x10306, ino=57016408, mode=0100644, nlink=1, uid=1000, gid=1000, rdev=0x0, size=8416, blksize=4096, blocks=24, atime=2022-09-23 12:31:49.280214712 -0700, mtime=2022-09-19 18:08:32 -0700, ctime=2022-09-23 12:31:50.120221442 -0700>
irb(main):007:0>
```

Additional: This is Linux, MX Linux 21, ruby 2.7.4p191 (2021-07-07 revision a21a3b7d23) [x86_64-linux-gnu].  The shell is Bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`File.stat`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/File.html#method-c-stat) just calls [`File::Stat.new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/File/Stat.html#method-c-new) and that will raise an exception if the file doesn't exist; this is the behaviour you're seeing.

Note that `/home/bear/Dropbox/.#NineFoxes.org` is a symlink (see the `Access: 0777/lrwxrwxrwx` in stat's output). Ruby's `File.stat` documentation doesn't say if it follows symlinks or not but [`File.lstat`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/File.html#method-c-lstat) says:

> Same as `File::stat`, but does not follow the last symbolic link. Instead, reports on the link itself.

so it is implied that `File.stat` will follow the symlink and stat what it points to.

So the `/home/bear/Dropbox/.#NineFoxes.org` symlink does exist but what the symlink references doesn't exist.